# Getting unique values for a file in python

Tags: python

I have a file like this:

```
20024
20008
20044
20024
20015
20087
20024
20070
20001
```

I wish to keep these numbers in order but get rid of repetitive ones. Only the unique ones should stay. I tried using a set for it but it gives me the error of unhashable type. If I convert it form a list to set, it doesn't seem to work.

```
labels=set()
with open("Y-labels.txt") as filer:
    for line in filer:
        labels.add(line.strip().split())
```

How can I get the unique numbers but in order?

Comment: read file line-by-line, check list if value is already there. if not, then store to list and write to new file. if already in list, DON'T write to new file.

Comment: You are splitting the line into an list of characters. Remove the split.

Comment: What do you mean with "repetitive"? I don't see any repetition in your numbers. It's also not clear what exactly you want. I suggest you provide a better example, with input actually having repetitions and with output.

Comment: Stephan, his question is pretty clear. He provides input sample to show the format he is working with. I am sure you know what duplicates are. Why are you nitpicking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OrderedDict`. Doing so will both (1) keep the fields in order and (2) give better complexity than iteratively adding values-one-by-one to a list while checking if the value is already not in the list.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
with open("Y-labels.txt") as filer:
    labels = OrderedDict([(x.strip(),0) for x in filer])

print labels.keys()
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the labels in a list and use a set for the already seen once:

```
labels = []
seen = set()
with open("Y-labels.txt") as filer:
    for line in filer:
        number = int(line)
        if not number in seen:
            labels.append(number)
            seen.add(number)
>>> labels
[20024, 20008, 20044, 20013, 20015, 20087, 20029, 20070, 20001]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use an `OrderedDict` using `.fromkeys` to create a unique ordered set of the lines using `map` to `str.strip` the line ending:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open("in.txt") as f:
    unique = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(map(str.strip,f)))
```

If you want the lines that actually only appear once, use a Counter Dict to count the occurrences and only keep lines where the count is 1:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("in.txt") as f:
    cn = Counter(map(str.strip, f))
    f.seek(0)  
    unique = [line for line in map(str.strip,f) if cn[line] == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps. Sets are unordered, but lists are.

```
labels = []
unique = {}
with open("Y-labels.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        labels.append(line)
        unique[line] = unique[line] + 1 if line in unique else 1

labels = [label for label in filter(lambda label: unique.pop(label, False), labels)]
```